# Why use int ever again?

Tags: java, types, jvm, int, long-integer

We are all nearly on 64bit machines and JVMs, RAM is cheap and performance rarely centers around low level JVM issues.

So why doesn't everyone STOP using int and move entirely to 64bit longs both in Java and in persistent (database) storage.

I know I'm never going to have 2^64 users, nor 2^64 languages, and if I get 2^64 stores open in the retail empire I'm not currently building I reckon I could buy myself a continent and retire.

Is there a downside other than 'you don't need 64bit numbers to store all possible pet store IDs'...?

Comment: I think this question might be more suitable for [programmers.se].

Comment: of course you got a valid point, but first what is your question and second what do you need 2^64 integer numbers for again?

Comment: A lot of people _do_ use longs for just about everything (even when they're not needed).  However, it is nice to know that you can use an int when you know it will suffice.  Do you have the same issue with _short_?

Comment: Nobody likes to be wasteful!

Comment: I have experienced identity burn in Sybase (before I knew about 'with identity gap') but this highlighted the issue we were vulnerable to ints running out in this scenario and we moved to long as a patch until we could rebuild the problem tables (which took a whole weekend).

Comment: In how many years US national debt will overflow 2^64 cents? Anyway most human size (calculation) problems fit 8-bits.

Comment: I had a professor who used to say "_memory is cheap, include the world_".  Well... when you get to the real world, there are times when you have to conserve memory.  For example: developing apps for phones and tablets.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen You meant 8 _bytes_, didn't you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of the increasing average RAM capacities of today's machines, why be wasteful when you're sure that the data you're representing will never exceed the size of an int?

Here's an example: I have a class that contains 10 instance variables represented with **int** primitives. Down the line I may have an infinite number of instances of this class running on my server. If I'd used **longs** instead (and not had the need for them), I would be wasting RAM as well as hard disk space if these object instances were being stored in a relational database.

So to answer your question, it's simply more scalable to be conservative with memory where you can be.